How to delete this emulator. This is not showing in the device manager
enter image description here
I am struggling to delete this emulator.
I was able to remove all those emulators from the device manager. I even delete my android studio and deleted all of the data but it is still there. I have tried avdmanager list command but there is no result.

Configured Android emulators are not part of the Android Studio installation. Instead they are stored in subfolders of .android in your home folder. Therefore reinstalling Android Studio has no effect on the emulators.

@Robert I have check that folder, Deleted .android folder too. But it is still there.
